# How to save the stream response of google plus after successful authentication in windows phone7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm integrating social network app google plus in my app.
I got successfull response after authentiation.
My doubt can we able to save the email and name as a strings and passing to another page through navigation service.

I need to save the stream and setting to strings.If anyone knows please help me.

This is the code which i've tried:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;

namespace OwnCloud.View.Page
{
    public partial class GooglePlusLoginPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {

        public App thisApp = Application.Current as App;
        GooglePlusTokens googlePlusTokens = new GooglePlusTokens();
        GooglePlusUserInfo googlePlusUserInfo = new GooglePlusUserInfo();

        public string result;
        String myemail;
        string Parameters = null;
        string ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        string ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        string RedirctedUri = "http://localhost";

        [DataContract]
        public class GooglePlusAccessToken
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "access_token")]
            public string AccessToken { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "refresh_token")]
            public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "expires_in")]
            public string ExpiresIn { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "token_type")]
            public string TokenType { get; set; }

        }
        [DataContract]
        public class GooglePlusUserProfile
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "id")]
            public string id { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "email")]
            public string email { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "name")]
            public string name { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "given_name")]
            public string given_name { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "family_name")]
            public string family_name { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "link")]
            public string link { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "picture")]
            public string picture { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "gender")]
            public string gender { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "birthday")]
            public string birthday { get; set; }

        }
        /*  public class Mylist
          {
              public string Email { get; set; }
              public string Gender { get; set; }
          }*/

        public GooglePlusLoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(GooglePlus_LoginPage_Loaded); //load google plus login page 
            var GooglePlusSerializerData = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(GooglePlusAccessToken));

        }

        //load google plus login page 
        void GooglePlus_LoginPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=" + RedirctedUri + "&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&client_id=" + ClientId;  //http://localhost 
            webBrowserGooglePlusLogin.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        }


        private void webBrowserGooglePlusLogin_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Uri.Host.Equals("localhost"))
            {
                webBrowserGooglePlusLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

                e.Cancel = true;
                int pos = e.Uri.Query.IndexOf("=");

                //get the access code 
                 string messageCode = pos > -1 ? e.Uri.Query.Substring(pos + 1) : null;

                //when code is not equeals to null get the access token
                if (messageCode != null)
                {
                    //get the access token 
                    Parameters = "code=" + messageCode + "&client_id=" + ClientId + "&client_secret=" + ClientSecret + "&redirect_uri=" + RedirctedUri + "&grant_type=authorization_code";
                    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
                    webRequest.Method = "POST";
                    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                    //string email="madhu.salvendra@gmail.com";




                    // Start web request
                    webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), webRequest);



                        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/Page/EditAccount.xaml?mailid="+<here i want to pass email-id>, UriKind.Relative));


                }

            }
        }
        void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {

            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
                // End the stream request operation
                Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);


                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Parameters);

                // Add the post data to the web request
                postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                postStream.Close();

                // Start the web request
                webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), webRequest);
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
            }

        }
        void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            try
            {
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

                using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult))
                {
                    using (var streamResponse = resp.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        var GooglePlusSerializerData = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(GooglePlusAccessToken));
                        var GooglePlusProfileData = GooglePlusSerializerData.ReadObject(streamResponse) as GooglePlusAccessToken;
                        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                            (Action<GooglePlusAccessToken>)((GooglePlusUserData) =>
                            {

                                //save the response
                                thisApp.AccessToken = googlePlusTokens.AccessToken = GooglePlusUserData.AccessToken;
                                googlePlusTokens.RefreshToken = GooglePlusUserData.RefreshToken;
                                googlePlusTokens.ExpiresIn = GooglePlusUserData.ExpiresIn;
                                googlePlusTokens.TokenType = GooglePlusUserData.TokenType;


                                // request user profile
                                RequestForUserProfile();


                            }), GooglePlusProfileData);

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {

            }
        }

        //request for user prifile
        void RequestForUserProfile()
        {

            //  var urlProfile = "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=" + thisApp.AccessToken;
            var urlProfile = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + thisApp.AccessToken;
            // web request user profile
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlProfile);
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(this.ResponseCallbackProfile), request);

        }


        // user profile response 
        private void ResponseCallbackProfile(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {

            try
            {
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

                using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult))
                {
                    using (var streamResponse = resp.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        var GooglePlusSerializerData = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(GooglePlusUserProfile));
                        var GooglePlusProfileData = GooglePlusSerializerData.ReadObject(streamResponse) as GooglePlusUserProfile;
                        var mydata = GooglePlusSerializerData.ReadObject(streamResponse) as Mylist;
                        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                            (Action<GooglePlusUserProfile>)((GooglePlusUserData) =>
                            {

                                thisApp.UserName = googlePlusUserInfo.UserName = GooglePlusUserData.name;
                                thisApp.UserImage = googlePlusUserInfo.UserPicture = GooglePlusUserData.picture;

                                if (thisApp.UserImage == null)
                                {
                                    thisApp.UserImage = googlePlusUserInfo.UserPicture = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_kvINpT6jtI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/IEAclp4PQbk/photo.jpg";
                                }
                                googlePlusUserInfo.UserBidthday = GooglePlusUserData.birthday;


                                thisApp.UserEmail = googlePlusUserInfo.UserEmail = GooglePlusUserData.email;
                                myemail = googlePlusUserInfo.UserEmail;
                                googlePlusUserInfo.UserFamilyName = GooglePlusUserData.family_name;
                                thisApp.UserGender = googlePlusUserInfo.UserGender = GooglePlusUserData.gender;
                                googlePlusUserInfo.UserGivenName = GooglePlusUserData.given_name;
                                googlePlusUserInfo.UserId = GooglePlusUserData.id;
                                googlePlusUserInfo.UserLink = GooglePlusUserData.link;
                                /*  IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
                                  if (!settings.Contains("name"))
                                  {
                                      // MessageBox.Show("First Time Add to Isolated Storage");
                                      settings.Add("name", GooglePlusProfileData.email);
                                      settings.Add("id", GooglePlusProfileData.id);
                                      settings.Add("email", GooglePlusProfileData.name);
                                      settings.Add("userType", GooglePlusProfileData.gender);
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                      // MessageBox.Show("Iso Stored Data Updated");
                                      settings["name"] = GooglePlusProfileData.name;
                                      settings["id"] = GooglePlusProfileData.id;
                                      settings["email"] = GooglePlusProfileData.email;
                                      settings["gender"] = GooglePlusProfileData.gender;
                                  }
                                  settings.Save();*/

                            }), GooglePlusProfileData);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your goal what you exactly need to do?

Comment: my goal to get the data of email,birthday,etc and passing to textbox.

Comment: To me it seems that your code should work for that purpose.

Comment: NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/Page/EditAccount.xaml?mailid="+GooglePlusUserData.email, UriKind.Relative)); but it is showing empty string

Comment: in textbox on editaccount page

Comment: can you share your project in a zip file?

Comment: how to share the file

Comment: You don't have a EditAccount.xaml page in your project anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You should move your

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/Page/EditAccount.xaml?mailid="+<here i want to pass email-id>, UriKind.Relative));
```

after this:

```
thisApp.UserEmail = googlePlusUserInfo.UserEmail = GooglePlusUserData.email;
myemail = googlePlusUserInfo.UserEmail;
googlePlusUserInfo.UserFamilyName = GooglePlusUserData.family_name;
thisApp.UserGender = googlePlusUserInfo.UserGender = GooglePlusUserData.gender;
googlePlusUserInfo.UserGivenName = GooglePlusUserData.given_name;
googlePlusUserInfo.UserId = GooglePlusUserData.id;
googlePlusUserInfo.UserLink = GooglePlusUserData.link;
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/Page/EditAccount.xaml?mailid="+googlePlusUserInfo.UserEmail, UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: i think navigation should call in this method                                                                                                                  private void webBrowserGooglePlusLogin_Navigating(object sender,  NavigatingEventArgs e)             {                                                                                         NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/Page/EditAccount.xaml?mailid="+googlePlusUserInfo.UserEmail, UriKind.Relative));}

Comment: If you're following this example http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Google%2B_authentication_in_Windows_Phone_application. There is where you should navigate to another page with the email address before that point you cannot  have the email.

Comment: how to get please post if you have any example.Please which suit my requirement

Comment: If you have a code to sync all the images from the windows phone7 and upload to server one after another please if you have post it or mail to me.Help me